# Exceptions as flow control, optimization

Tags: c++, exception, gcc

I'm abusing exceptions as flow control in gcc, is there a way to make it emit somewhat optimized code?

```
shiny f(legacy const &l)
try
{
    auto convert_i = [](int i) -> int
    {
        switch(i)
        {
            case 1:    return 5;
            case 2:    return 9;
            default:   throw 0;
        }
    };

    return shiny
    {
        .i = convert_i(l.i)
    };
}
catch(int)
{
    return shiny { .invalid = true };
}
```

So I have a lot of lambdas, these are used while filling out a struct, and pretty much all of these can fail, so writing this code without exceptions would be a verbose mess. At the same time, the exception never leaves the current function, and the only reason for the compiler to generate exception handling code at all is to give the debugger a chance to intervene.

This project uses gcc as the compiler, and is unlikely to change away. The generated code uses a lot of space to construct, throw, catch and ignore an exception object, can this be avoided?

Comment: Your code looks like it could use "std::optional" and not use exceptions at all. Your convert would just leave the optional unititialized.

Comment: @PepijnKramer That would require changing the definition of the `shiny` struct to include those optionals, which will not always be possible. And it would probably also take up more space, right?

Comment: No not really, I see @Frodyne already made the example :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to challenge the premise of your question. You say *"so writing this code without exceptions would be a verbose mess"*... but is that true? What about the following?

Aside from that: I would hazard a guess that all those local lambdas would also cause a lot of overhead. Why not make them static functions with an out-parameter `bool &conversion_failed`. No need to capture local variables and generate temporary function pointers (unless those are optimized out by gcc anyway).

```
shiny f(legacy const &l)
{
    bool conversion_failed = false;

    auto convert_i = [&conversion_failed](int i) -> int
    {
        // Feel free to omit this line if you can accept that all conversions are run even after any one failed.
        if (conversion_failed) return 0; // or any nonsense value
        switch(i)
        {
            case 1:    return 5;
            case 2:    return 9;
            default:   conversion_failed = true;
                       return 0; // or any nonsense value
        }
    }

    shiny result {
        .i = convert_i(l.i),
        // etc...
    };
    result.invalid = conversion_failed;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hm, I'd have to capture that bool, but that sounds viable.

Comment: @SimonRichter You are right of course, added that to the example...

Answer (score 3):

Changing your code to use `std::optional` would be able to remove the exception path completely. There are several ways to do this, but a fairly straight translation of your code could look like this:

```
shiny f(legacy const &l)
{
    auto convert_i = [](int i) -> std::optional<int>
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 1:
            return 5;
        case 2:
            return 9;
        default:
            return {};
        }
    };

    auto c = convert_i(l.i);
    if (c)
        return shiny{.i = c.value()};
    else
        return shiny{.invalid = true};
}
```

Comment: The main concern is that there are *many* conversions, and I'd like to avoid having to write conditions for all of them.